# WP_Query posts by cat an tags not working

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

I'm trying to get some posts by cat an tags. This is what I got so far but is not working.

Any help, it would be great...

```
$pots = new WP_Query(array('cat' => array (591),
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array('my tag', 'my tag2'),
        ),
    ),
     'posts_type' => 'post',
     'showposts' => 32,
     'paged' => $paged,
     'order' => 'desc',
     'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is fine, just about the tag, I think I should use slug instead of name like my code

```
$pots = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat' => array(591),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('my_tag', 'my_tag2'),
                'operator' => 'AND',
            ),
        ),
        'posts_type' => 'post',
        'showposts' => 32,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'order' => 'desc',
        'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    )
);
```